# How to convert PyTorch tensor dimension?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have tensor with dimension (210,2) using PyTorch. I want to convert it into (15,14,2).
Anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
x = torch.randn(210, 2)
x = x.reshape(15,14,2)
```